# Python Request .....When is json not json. json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am using Python Requests to get submit a json request to a home automation server (Homeseer3).  I do get a response.  If I .....

```
print(reponse.text)
```

I get a lot of text which starts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/js-listbox-style.css" type="text/css" />
```

If I....

```
print(response.content)
```

I get a lot of text which starts:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />\r\n\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/js-listbox-style.css" type="text/css" />\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.ui.timepicker.css
```

If I enter the same command into a browser, I get a very nice page with 3 tabs: Headers, raw data and json.

I want to "get at" the json device data which is in the response...[screen grab showing json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUcqE.png)

but if I enter

````
```
response.json()
```
````

i get "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

I have read all of the similar post here on StackOverflow but none of them fit.... as far as I can see.

I hope someone can help.

Whilst adding tags I found Python-Requests-Html.......  is this the answer ?

Comment: .json() is used on json returned response. your response look like HTML you need HTML parser

Comment: Thank you, Lone_ranger.  In case anyone else comes across this problem......

I was not formulating the "Request" properly.  I was sending the following payload to my server (192,168,x,x),  json={"request": "getStatus", "ref": "41"} .  It was ignoring the payload and sending back the html of its webserver.

If I sent params = {"request": "getStatus", "ref": "41"} to the server  "192.168.x.x/JSON" I did get back json formaulated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Lone_ranger. In case anyone else comes across this problem...... I was not formulating the "Request" properly. I was sending the following payload to my server (192,168,x,x), json={"request": "getStatus", "ref": "41"} . It was ignoring the payload and sending back the html of its webserver. If I sent params = {"request": "getStatus", "ref": "41"} to the server "192.168.x.x/JSON" I did get back json formaulated data.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32144344)